# They were listening scared

Tags: verbs, adjectives, sentence-usage

> ***They were listening scared.***

Is there anything wrong with this sentence? I searched Google Books and this expression does not seem to appear anywhere:

> ***listening scared***

Not even Ngram recognizes it as a valid arrangement of words.

Comment: Grammatically, it's fine. Semantically, it would also be fine in the right context.

Comment: I'm talking about the dogs in a village, after a gunshot thundered at midnight. They stopped barking, listening scared.

Comment: If it's the dogs that were "listening" and 'scared', then it's fine. "Scared" is an adjective functioning as a predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a 'predicand' (the subject "they") and adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure.

Comment: It looks weird to me but I think it's mostly because of the punctuation.  I would much prefer "They were listening **,** scared" because that emphasizes that they were listening, and that they were scared.  The version without the comma makes it look like they were one thing called "listening scared".

Comment: I don't know about that.  *Scared* isn't an adverb.

Comment: "Scared" is not an adverb, it's an adjective, but it is still an adjunct in clause structure. It's predicative of course since it relates to the subject, but it is not a dependent in the subject NP, which is just "they", so it cannot be seen as a modifier or complement of "they". It is precisely because depictives like this cut across the contrast between complements and adjuncts that they are called 'predicative adjuncts'.

Comment: @stangdon, I'm afraid that BillJ is right. Check out this example, "But in the end, before they get caught, most of them are *running scared*." It is from  the novel, "The Shadow of Your Smile", by Mary Higgins Clark.

Comment: Could you explain what "scary listening is"? Regardless of the grammar, I can't make logical sense of it. Are you saying they were listening intently because they were scared?

Comment: *Intently* is a good adverb, @user3169, whereas I use the adjective *scared* for describing two actions in one expression: they were listening, and they were scared. Both actions are related to the thunder of the gunshot. You are right up to some degree, as they were more than attentive, they were afraid.

Comment: @QOTSA - Good point, but "running scared" is kind of an idiom and stock phrase, so I'm not sure it's a good example of the general case.

Comment: @stangdon - Indeed. Now I reread the paragraph, and "running" it has the meaning of "becoming".